# MongoDB performance issues

Tags: mongodb

We are currently using a collection called `items` which contain 10 million entries in our MongoDB database.

This collection contains (amongst many others) two columns named `title` and `country_code`. One such entry looks like this

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("566acf868fdd29578f35e8db"),
  "feed": ObjectId("566562f78fdd2933aac85b42"),
  "category": "Mobiles & Tablets",
  "title": "360DSC Crystal Clear Transparent Ultra Slim Shockproof TPU Case for Iphone 5 5S (Transparent Pink)",
  "URL": "http://www.lazada.co.id/60dsc-crystal-clear-transparent-ultra-slim-shockproof-tpu-case-for-iphone-5-5s-transparent-pink-3235992.html",
  "created_at": ISODate("2015-12-11T13:28:38.470Z"),
  "barcode": "36834ELAA1XCWOANID-3563358",
  "updated_at": ISODate("2015-12-11T13:28:38.470Z"),
  "country_code": "ID",
  "picture-url": "http://id-live.slatic.net/p/image-2995323-1-product.jpg",
  "price": "41000.00"
}
```

The cardinality on column `country_code` is very high. We have created two text indices for these columns:

```
db.items.createIndex({title: "text", country_code: "text"})
```

In our examples we try to query:

```
db.items.find({"title": { "$regex": "iphone", "$options": "i" }, country_code: "US"}).limit(10)
```

A query which takes around 6 seconds to complete, which seems unusually high for this type of database.

Whenever we try a `country_code` (e.g., country_code: "UK") that has less results, it will return results within milliseconds.

Would there be any particular reason, why these queries differ so much in their time to return results?

EDIT:
All answers here helped so if you have this issue yourself, try all of 3 of the solutions. Could only mark 1 as correct though.

Comment: the reason is because vanilla indexes cannot typically help with $regex based queries. You might have better luck with a full-text index

Comment: you may use .explain() to see what is going on..

Comment: Can you please post the output of `db.items.createIndex({title: "text", country_code: "text"}).explain()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch around the order of the fields in your index. *Order matters*.

```
db.items.createIndex({country_code: "text", title: "text"})
```

Ensure you maintain this order when querying:

```
db.items.find({country_code: "US", "title": { "$regex": "iphone", "$options": "i" }}).limit(10)
```

What this will do is drastically decrease the amount of `title` fields you need so search a substring for.

Also as mentioned by @Jaco, you should take advantage of your "text" index. See [how to query a text index here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/text/#search-for-a-single-word).

Answer (score 0):

As you do an exact search on `country_code`, you can add the text index on `title` only:

```
db.items.createIndex({title:"text"})
```

and add a seperate index on `country_code`:

```
db.items.createIndex({country_code:1})
```

As you have defined a `text` index on `title` you don't have to use a regular expression, but instead you can do a text search like this:

```
db.items.find({$text:{$search:"iphone"},country_code:"US"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build an index like `{country_code: 1, title: "text"}`.

Equal is much more faster than regular expression, make it count.